# Conditional filter of entire group for DataFrameGroupBy

Tags: pandas

If I have the following data

```
>>> data = pd.DataFrame({'day': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4], 
'hour':[4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 7]})
>>> data
   day  hour
0    1     4
1    1     5
2    1     6
3    1     7
4    2     4
5    2     5
6    2     6
7    2     7
8    3     4
9    4     7
```

And I would like to keep only days where `hour` has 4 unique values then I would think to do something like this

```
>>> data.groupby('day').apply(lambda x: x[x['hour'].nunique() == 4])
```

But this returns `KeyError: True`

I am hoping to get this

```
>>> data
   day  hour
0    1     4
1    1     5
2    1     6
3    1     7
4    2     4
5    2     5
6    2     6
7    2     7
```

Where we see that where `day == 3` and `day == 4` have been filtered because when grouped by day they don't have 4 unique values of `hour`. I'm doing this at scale so simply filtering where `(day == 3) & (day == 4)` is not an option. I think grouping would be a good way to do this but can't get it to work. Anyone have experience with applying functions to `DataFrameGroupBy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you actually need to `filter` the data:

```
>>> data.groupby('day').filter(lambda x: x['hour'].nunique() == 4)
   day  hour
0    1     4
1    1     5
2    1     6
3    1     7
4    2     4
5    2     5
6    2     6
7    2     7
```

Comment: Yes, `filter` is what I needed. I found this in the docs (0.20.1) http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration

Comment: @spies006 Thanks, you're right, it's actually there, it is just missing in the [API docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html); I'll send an issue.

Comment: Very neat answer !

Comment: The documentation [has been updated](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16483) now.